# SwiftUI Prevent line break for a hyphenated word without affecting the scaling

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to prevent a line break for the word sugar-free which is caused by this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var enteredText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.blue
                .frame(height: 300)
            Text("It is a sugar-free drink!")
                .font(Font.system(size: 52).weight(.black).italic())
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .padding()
            TextField("enter text", text: $enteredText)
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

I can achieve this by adding a newline:

```
 Text("It is a \nsugar-free drink!")
```

[image]

But this causes an issue if the keyboard appears:

[image]

The text is cropped due to the newline character and lack of space.

What I would like to have is:

[image]
[image]

Is there a simple solution to this problem which does not include resizing of fields or some overly-complicated logic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use non-breaking hyphen \U2011

e.g.

```
This is non\U2011breaking
```

Answer (score 3):

A [non-breaking hyphen](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2011.html) should work:

```
Text("It is a sugar\u{2011}free drink!")
```

Comment: For anyone who will come across this: preview in XCode may show you '\u{2011}' instead of the hyphen but it will work just fine on the actual device.