# SwiftUI: How to suppress line breaks for a part of texts?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to prevent line breaks in a parts of SwiftUI Text - for example, when I have label like `Car speed is 10 m/s.`, I would like to force SwiftUI to keep the `m/s` (or preferrably `10 m/s`) together (but still allow it to do linebreaks elsewhere in text).

With default settings, the label might break like this `10 m<br>/s`, which I'd like to prevent.

If the character in question would have been dash, I could use a [non-breaking dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566439/swiftui-prevent-line-break-for-a-hyphenated-word-without-affecting-the-scaling), but no such luck here.

Comment: Non-breaking space should work (U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE), I used such in .strings. Put it between number and unit.

Comment: I tried non-breaking spaces, but the text was broken anyway...